# GIT .env on local vs remote

Tags: git, push

During development of product I need to keep some configuration file in my repository on local machine. How can I keep pushing everything to the remote repo and keep the configuration file only on local machine?

Anytime I push to remote git delete the config file from my local repo.

Comment: "*Anytime I push to remote git delete the config file from my local repo."* Push **never deletes** files from the local repo. Do you have a `pre-push` hook?

Comment: you could stash your files before pushing and pop it out once it is required.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just add you file into the .gitignore

```
######################
# ENV configs
######################
.env
```

or custom file path:

```
/src/main/resources/fileName.env
```